# Plotting within a for-loop - legend doesn't show appropriate line colors

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to plot 3 lines in a single window. The 3 lines depend on the variable `nbPoints`. The problem is: the lines in the legend only have 1 color: red. What is a solution for this?

Thanks!

```
hold on
nbPoints = [6 10 14];
for nb = nbPoints
    interpolatiepunten = linspace(-1,1,nb);
    veelterm = interpolerende_veelterm(interpolatiepunten, rungeFunctie, 'lagrange');

    y = zeros(201);
    index = 1;
    for i = -1:0.01:1
        y(index) = veelterm.val(i);
        index = index + 1;
    end

    if (nb == 6)
        color = 'r';
    elseif (nb == 10)
        color = 'b';
    else
        color = 'g';
    end
    plot(-1:0.01:1, y, color);
end
legend({'a', 'b', 'c'});
% legend('a', 'b', 'c'); does not work
hold off
```

Comment: I am familiar with MATLAB but unfamiliar with this loop notation 
for nb = nbPoints, is that meant to be like that? Perhaps change it to for i=1:length(nbPoints) nb = nbPoints(i)

Comment: @Muckle_ewe The loop notation `nb = nbPoints` works just like a foreach-loop in any other language. Like `for x in array:` in Python or `for(x : array) {}` in Java.

Comment: You're creating `y` as a matrix on purpose?

Comment: @OlegKomarov `y` is just a vector

Comment: Then you forgot a comma in your code.

Comment: This must be the most stupid mistake of today. Thanks! It's solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I've used for-loops with plot colour cycling before, using this method:

```
Colortypes = ['r','b','g'];
nbPoints = [6 10 14];
x = [1:10];

figure
hold on

loop_ind = 1;
for ii=nbPoints
y = ii*x;
linespecvec = Colortypes(loop_ind);
plot(x,y,linespecvec)
loop_ind = loop_ind+1;
end

legend('a','b','c')
```

So, the line colors are looped through just like nbPoints is looped through. The resulting plot is:

[image]

Comment: AND... for bonus points, you can also specify a line type (such as dash-dot, dash-dash, dots, etc), and loop through that as well.